# Show that cancellation law does not hold for $<\mathbb{R},•>$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please help me in [showing that](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=9_GGZBQm8OcC&pg=PA51&dq=distilling%20ideas%20katz%20Show%20that%20the%20Cancellation%20Law%20fails%20for%20(R,.),%20thus%20confirming%20that&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjZprvo7K7tAhWCyjgGHYu8BMwQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=distilling%20ideas%20katz%20Show%20that%20the%20Cancellation%20Law%20fails%20for%20(R%2C.)%2C%20thus%20confirming%20that&f=false) cancellation law does not hold for Reals under $•$ operation, i.e. $<\mathbb{R},•>$.

Let, $R_1=a, R_2=b, R_3=c$

$R_1•R_3=R_2•R_3 \nRightarrow R_1 = R_2$

$a.c= b.c \nRightarrow a = b$

I can not find a such example, nor can prove as shown above.

Comment: Take $a=1,b=2,c=0$.

Comment: $5 \cdot 0 = 13 \cdot 0$  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reals, being a field, honour something *close to* a cancellation law: if $(a-b)\cdot c=0$ then $a-b=0$ or $c=0$, i.e. if $ac=bc$ then $a=b$ or $c=0$.

Comment: Thanks. Please tell if can extend reasoning to complex numbers. I mean that division by zero is an invalid operation for complex numbers too.

Comment: @jiten It works for any field, including $\Bbb C$. It even works for some other structures, such as $\Bbb H$, which isn't a field because it doesn't commute, and $\Bbb O$, which also doesn't associate. And the fact that $c=0$ is a cancellation counterexample works in any number system where you can multiply by $0$.